# Passing a function on the content of a HTML textarea in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

How can I pass a function on the content of a HTML textarea if the content is an array?

eg:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8v0kg.png

the `textarea.value` is a string but I want to use a javascript function such that `textarea.value.forEach()` works

Comment: The content is ALWAYS a string. You have to parse that string. `JSON.parse()` *may* work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use JSON.parse() function to convert string into json object

you can find more here [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)